# Forcing Mathematica to use certain simplification rule

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to force *Mathematica* to use following transformation function

```
tf[e_] := 
  e /. {BarnesG[1 + 2 x_] :> 
     2^(x (2 x - 1)) Pi^(-x - 1/2) (
      BarnesG[3/2 + x] BarnesG[1/2 + x] BarnesG[1 + x]^2)/
      BarnesG[1/2]^2};
```

After evaluation of the previous line simplification

```
Simplify[BarnesG[1 + 2 x], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]
```

does not yield desirable result but instead returns original

```
BarnesG[1 + 2 x]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I guess `Simplify` does not use your rule, because the result would be more complex ([`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeafCount.html)) than the original input.

The following is really a hack which seems only to work because of internal behavior of `Simplify`.

```
ClearAll[tf, rule];
tf[BarnesG[1 + 2 x_]] := rule;
Simplify[BarnesG[1 + 2 x], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}];
rule = 2^(x (2 x - 1)) Pi^(-x - 
      1/2) (BarnesG[3/2 + x] BarnesG[1/2 + x] BarnesG[1 + x]^2)/
    BarnesG[1/2]^2;
```

Now you can call `Simplify` as you did

```
Simplify[BarnesG[1 + 2 x], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Possible (!) explanation

I assume the following happens: When you call this the first time, without `rule` having any value

```
tf[BarnesG[1 + 2 x_]] := rule;
Simplify[BarnesG[1 + 2 x], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}];
```

then `Simplify` seems to cache that the simplification to `rule` is better, because it has a lower `LeafCount`. Once this is done, the rule is applied, even if `rule` is now set to an expression which is more complex than the original one.

Comment: I am using v9.0.1 and this does not work for me. It returns unevaluated.

Comment: @RunnyKine Indeed, when I tried it, it worked. Let me investigate.

Comment: @RunnyKine Can you try again. It seems I accidentally revealed some cashing issue, which enables this hack.

Comment: I get @halirutan's result (V9.0.1, Mac).

Comment: So this works now. I wonder why it only works if you use `Simplify` twice as in your code.